# filterable portfolio with wordpress and jquery

Tags: jquery, child-theme

I used this tutorial in creating portfolio page:
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery/

I am working on Thematic child theme: http://www.integritycorp.org/study/?page_id=103#all

This is the code I used:

- http://gist.github.com/3024754
- http://gist.github.com/3024748

Why doesn’t the filtering work when I click on one of the tags?

Comment: filterable.js is 404 not found. Use your browser's error console.

Comment: it is now exist but still not working

Comment: ok its working only if i added filterable.js to the parent theme

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

When enqueueing scripts in a child theme directory, use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead of [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri). In the case of a child theme, `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the parent theme's directory.

```
function enqueue_filterable(){
    wp_register_script(
        'filterable',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/filterable.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'filterable' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_filterable' );
```

Comment: now i use quick sand but i wonder why not working http://www.integritycorp.org/study/?page_id=34